# Does the LOCATE() function in DB2 have a limit to its length?

Tags: sql, db2, locate

I'm trying to search for a text string in a really big text field (like 100 million characters big). `Select locate(LT.LARGE_TEXT, 'text to find') from LARGE_TEXT LT` is the query I tried. The `locate` function is giving me an error:

> Error during SQLFetch  22001(-433)[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664]
> SQL0433N  Value " <Rat" is too long.  SQLSTATE=22001  (0.27 secs)

The text field is essentially storing a complete json file, and I need to find certain things in it.

Comment: Seems like the found rows are too long. Test `select count(*) from ... where locate() ...`

Comment: Please include the SQL Query that actually generated the error.  It sounds like you're trying to return the JSON text to your client, and the client driver can't cope with 100MB+ is a single column in a single row.  But, as you haven't included the query, we're just guessing.

Comment: Do you mean to use the Locate() in the where clause? Like the query would be Select count(*) from Table where locate(columnname, 'text to find') > 0? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Select locate(LT.LARGE_TEXT, 'text to find')
  from LARGE_TEXT LT is the query I tried

Comment: I believe Locate works on string types with a length no greater than 32k.  A CLOB can be much, much larger than that and you need to use DBMS_LOB.INSTR instead.

Comment: I tried DBMS_LOB.INSTR and it worked great. Thanks, Jim!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First, you seem to have reversed the function arguments. According to the [reference documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-locate), the invocation is

```
LOCATE(<search-string>, <source-string> [, <start> [CODEUNITS16|CODEUNITS32|OCTETS]])
```

Second, both `<search-string>` and `<source-string>` arguments are of the type `VARCHAR` or cast to `VARCHAR`, and `VARCHAR` has the [maximum length of 32672 bytes](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=s-sql-xml-limits). As suggested in comments, you should use the [`DBMS_LOB.INSTR` function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dlm-instr-function-return-location-nth-occurrence-given-pattern).

Comment: Please take a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)